# Getting Device Location in Background & Android Background Restrictions

Tags: android, android-service, job-scheduling, android-gps, background-service

As Android is improving in terms of optimizations it's getting really hard for developers to choose from given options, for example, **Background Service** and **Getting User Location in Background** in all versions of android like Uber.

So my simple question is **How can we track user location in all versions of android keeping eye on 4.4> & <9.0 restrictions?** Is there a single way for google recommendation sample which will show developers to achieve this in all SDK versions?

There are several ways that documentation has mentioned but as a developer, more options means more confusion in choosing the best option for getting a device located in the background.

As everyone knows about new doze mode and app standby buckets, how can we tackle all these scenarios to create a Perfect and Battery optimized method for achieving this?  I have been reading the official android doc but when it comes to practical implementation there are many complications to handle this in all SDK versions from 4.4 to 9.0 with a single and recommended way.

Some of the options are:

1. Services
2. WorkManager
3. JobScheduler
4. AlarmManager and many more.

I have been searching the best method to achieve this but some of them work till 6.0 only and failed in 7+ due to background restrictions for battery optimization.

**Note** there is no answer on StackOverflow which have explained this implementation keeping eye on all SDK versions from 4.4 to 9.0

Comment: The big question here is how often do you want to get the location/what accuracy do you need?  Foreground Service is the way to get it with the highest frequency, but you'll still be limited when the device is asleep (screen turned off). WorkManager/JobScheduler/AlarmManager will be more or less equal, as all of them are built on top of the same functionality.

Comment: in short i want to get location as Uber does. it can be few sec more or less but the question is will that method will work on all versions from 4.4 to 9.0 ? that is most confusing thing for most of the developers because of new restrictions

Comment: Foreground Service is probably the way to go.  Its also why modern versions of Uber have the notification when its in the background (you need the notification to run a foreground service).  Of course it would still be possible for the OS to kill your service for resources, but it will be lower down the list.